# How to write xsd for the following xml?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following XML:

```
<xml>
    <columns>
        <column fruit="apple" />
        <column fruit="peach" />
    </columns>
    <items>
        <item date="10.10.2009">
            <apple price="3" />
            <peach price="5" />
        </item>
        <item date="10.10.2010">
            <apple price="4" />
            <peach price="2" />
        </item>
    </items>
</xml>
```

Inside `xml.columns.item` tag can be tags with the same name as defined in `xml.columns..@fruit` attribute and in the same order. All tags inside `xml.columns.item` are always have the same attribute `xml.columns.item..@price`.

Does anybody know how to define this in XSD?

Comment: ... but I see no "xml.columns.item" tags... did you mean "xml.items.item"? Or "xml.columns.column"?

Comment: Maybe you should add - for any other responder's benefit - that you're using this on a **Mac** .....

Comment: @marc_s Hi Marc, good idea to tell to people that I use Mac. Didn't think about it because XSD is platform independend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't represent this in XSD. If you are looking to cross reference data then you should look at using ID/IDREF types. Chek [ID/IDREF: sample solution](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XML_-_Managing_Data_Exchange/The_many-to-many_relationship)